# GitHub Actions dynamic output

Tags: github-actions

Consider this action.yml:

```
inputs:
  names:
    description: Names to be retrieved
    
runs:
  using: 'composite'
  steps:
    - id: retrieve-values
      shell: bash
      run: |
        set -euxo pipefail
        clean_params=$(echo "${{ inputs.names }}" | tr -d ' ')
        
        # Split the string at commas and store the parts in an array
        IFS=',' read -ra items <<< "${clean_params}"
        
        for item in "${items[@]}"; do
          value=$(./command "$item")
          echo "${item}=${value}" >> "$GITHUB_OUTPUT"
        done
```

Ideally, would like to access values in the form of:

`${{ steps.retrieve-values.outputs.dynamic_name }}`

Is there any way to return all of the **dynamic generated outputs** into the workflow calling the action?

Any alternatives?

Answer (score 1):

You could do something like:

```
outputs:
  dynamic_values:
    description: Dynamically generated values
    value: ${{ steps.retrieve-values.outputs.dynamic_values }}

runs:
  using: 'composite'
  steps:
    - id: retrieve-values
      shell: bash
      run: |
        set -euxo pipefail
        clean_params=$(echo "${{ inputs.names }}" | tr -d ' ')
        
        # Split the string at commas and store the parts in an array
        IFS=',' read -ra items <<< "${clean_params}"
        
        dynamic_values=""
        for item in "${items[@]}"; do
          value=$(./command "$item")
          echo "${item}=${value}" >> "$GITHUB_OUTPUT"
          dynamic_values="${dynamic_values}${item}=${value}\n"
        done
        
        echo "::set-output name=dynamic_values::${dynamic_values}"
```

then you can access them with in GHA with
${{ steps.retrieve-values.outputs.dynamic_values }}

Comment: Isn't `set-output` deprecated?